# Keras tuning that prefers faster models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to tune hyperparameters to get a sense of what values are best in tensorflow keras models. I'm going to use the best model in a minimax algorithm, so speed of evaluation is important due to the amount of estimations for the algorithm. Also, the speed of tuning is made much longer by evaluating models that I can see are barely adding accuracy but take much longer to fit.

In short, some of the models kt.Hyperband spits out have marginally higher accuracy but take much more time to fit and predict. Is there a way to value accuracy while preferring simpler, faster models?

Here is my current code:

```
!pip install -q -U keras-tuner
import keras_tuner as kt

def model_builder(hp):
    global val_dataset
    global train_dataset
    global test_dataset
    model = keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(hp.Int('conv1filter', min_value=32, max_value=512*3, step=512/2),
                               hp.Int('conv1kernal', min_value=2, max_value=20, step=2), 
                               padding="same", 
                               activation="relu", 
                               input_shape=(14,8,8)),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=1e-05),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(hp.Int('conv2filter', min_value=32, max_value=512*3, step=512/2),
                               hp.Int('conv2kernal', min_value=2, max_value=20, step=2), 
                               padding="same", 
                               activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=1e-05),
        layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hp.Int('dense1', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hp.Int('dense2', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32),  activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hp.Int('dense3', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh'),

  ])
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                loss='mean_absolute_error',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='val_accuracy',
                     max_epochs=10,
                     overwrite=True,
                     directory='my_dir30',
                     project_name='intro_to_kt30')
stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=5)
tuner.search(x_train, y_train,validation_data = (x_val, y_val), epochs=50, callbacks=[stop_early])

# Get the optimal hyperparameters
best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
# Build the model with the optimal hyperparameters and train it on the data for 50 epochs
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,validation_data = (x_val, y_val), epochs=50)

val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1
hypermodel = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

# Retrain the model
hypermodel.fit(x_train, y_train,validation_data = (x_val, y_val), epochs=best_epoch)
eval_result = hypermodel.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print("[test loss, test accuracy]:", eval_result)
hypermodel.save('/notebooks/saved_model/my_model')
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this as I do not have the dataset for your network, but from the docs:

> objective: A string, keras_tuner.Objective instance, or a list of keras_tuner.Objectives and strings. If a string, the direction of the optimization (min or max) will be inferred. If a list of keras_tuner.Objective, we will minimize the sum of all the objectives to minimize subtracting the sum of all the objectives to maximize. The objective argument is optional when Tuner.run_trial() or HyperModel.fit() returns a single float as the objective to minimize.

It looks like there is built-in support for more than one metric. It is unclear how to define complexity, one example can be `math.log(num_layers) * math.log(num_parameters)` or another example can be the time needed to run inference over a large batch of random data (maybe averaged over multiple trials). I suggest the following (untested) code, that will probably help you  towards a correct and satisfying implementation.

```
import math
import keras_tuner as kt


# Define the composite objective function to be used in model_builder
def composite_objective(hp):
    global val_dataset
    global train_dataset
    global test_dataset
    
    # Define the model architecture
    model = keras.Sequential([
        # ... Define your model layers here ...
    ])
    
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    
    # Compile the model with the specified learning rate
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
        loss='mean_absolute_error',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    
    # Calculate the model complexity
    num_layers = len(model.layers)
    num_parameters = model.count_params()
    complexity = - (math.log(num_layers) * math.log(num_parameters))  
    # Adjust this formula as per your preference, complexity should be low, so negative sign in front
    
    return {'accuracy': model.evaluate(...), 'complexity': complexity}

# Define the tuner with the custom objective
tuner = kt.Hyperband(
    composite_objective,
    max_epochs=10,
    overwrite=True,
    directory='my_dir30',
    project_name='intro_to_kt30'
)

# Rest of your code...
```

You can multiply the performance metric by a constant to regulate the tradeoff towards accuracy or efficiency.